# Weird checkbox issue in my app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a weird issue in my checkboxes using Angular

I have something like

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll"/> check all
</div>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedItem[item.id]" ng-checked="checkAll"/>    
    {{item.title}}
</div>

<button type="button" ng-click="click()"></button>
```

js

```
$scope.selectedItem = [];
$scope.click = function(){
    console.log($scope.selectedItem) -> [356: true, 123: true] 
}
```

In my console.log, it output `356:true` and `123:true`.  `356 and 124` are both IDs but I am not sure why do they have true for each of them. I was hoping to get

`[356, 123]` as my result. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Plunker should fix your problem. Basically, you are trying to pass an integer to `ng-model` hoping it will somehow bind to the item with that integer ID. However, this is not allowed. AngularJS reads the value passed to `ng-model` as a variable, and since JavaScript is [loosely-typed](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/03/understanding-loose-typing-in.html), it automatically assigns it a ["truthy"](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) value since you didn't explicitly pre-define it.

This is why you were getting `365: true` and `123: true` instead of `[365, 123]`.

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKAWbOvYjdwsl8BcmkAS?p=preview)

The code below modifies the way in which you check all the checkboxes: instead of using `ng-checked`, it uses `ng-clicked` and loops through the `$scope.items` array to look for items with an `isChecked` value of `$scope.checked`. I realize this is a step backward in efficiency, but the trade-off is that it easily allows each checkbox to have its own truthy/falsy variable for `ng-model` to indicate if it is checked.

If you wanted to preserve your original "checkAll" functionality with `ng-checked`, you'd have to find a way to dynamically create variables for each checkbox's `ng-model` value while having it work in harmony with `ng-checked`. This was the first approach that came to mind and I know it can be improved, but this should get you started.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-click="checkAll(checked)" /> check all
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" />    
            {{item.title}}
        </div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="click()">Click me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        id: 365,
        title: 'item1',
        isChecked: true
    }, {
        id: 123,
        title: 'item2',
        isChecked: true
    }];

    $scope.checked = true;

    $scope.checkAll = function() {
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            $scope.items[i].isChecked = $scope.checked;
        }
    };

    $scope.click = function() {
        var selectedItems = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if($scope.items[i].isChecked) {
                selectedItems.push($scope.items[i].id);
            }
        }
        console.log(selectedItems);
    };
});
```